# Handling Custom TableViewCell's(created in .xib with autolayout) Selections

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell which has button that when clicked reveals a checked box.
Now I am creating this in xib and using a tableView to load it.
 My problem is I need to set the selection state of the cell to true.
But when I do that reused cells lose selection property.
Is there any way to force the tableView to accept the cells selection?

Comment: Take one BOOL property & Set BOOL property to YES for every checked UITableViewCell.

Comment: @SahebSingh I was using xib's and i noticed the selection was never maintained by the custom cell. I never found out why? Once autolayout was switched off the selections came back

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSIndexPath *idxPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:idxPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Comment: This works for non xib created cells. Cells created using xib is not retaining state unless actual user-input selection is done. Any thoughts on that